# Joi array validation ignoring nested keys required

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, hapi.js, joi

Joi array required validation not working. I have an array userData which contain objects, keys dateMilli and value. I put required everywhere But if I pass an empty array of userData []. It is not throwing any error.

Joi Version is *"@hapi/joi": "^16.1.8"*, struggling with Joi docs but nothing works.

userId is "123" and userData is []

```
const data = { userId, userData };
const schema = Joi.object({
    userId: Joi.string().required(),
    userData: Joi.array().items({
        dateMilli: Joi.number().required(),
        value: Joi.string().valid("YES", "NO").required()
    }).required(),
});

let validate = schema.validate(data);
if (!validate || validate.hasOwnProperty("error")) {
        return res.send("Invalid parameters");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `.min` with array to disallow empty arrays.

try this

```
const data = {"userId": "123", "userData": []};
const Joi = require("@hapi/joi");
const schema = Joi.object({
  "userId": Joi.string().required(),
  "userData": Joi.array().items({
    "dateMilli": Joi.number().required(),
    "value": Joi.string().valid("YES", "NO").required()
  }).min(1).required()
});

const validate = schema.validate(data);
console.log(validate);
```

Comment: Can you mark it as answer for other people’s reference?